# Securing implicit tokens (Example: Moltin)

Tags: web-application, http, oauth, authorization, api

I'm fairly new to security but I'm trying to understand how companies have their APIs set. One such case is [Moltin's Implicit Token](https://docs.moltin.com/api/basics/authentication/implicit-token).

Basically they provide you with a read-only (for the most part) token that you can get by a POST request and providing the parameters:

1. `client_id` (this is publicly known)
2. `grant_type` (which would be "implicit")

In their docs, they say that implicit tokens are generally for front-end applications, however I'm not sure what the point of this is. What is the benefit if the client_id is exposed thus allowing anyone to generate these tokens? On top of that, they are only allowed access to non-sensitive data. It is odd to me because visitors to your shop would be given a token just to visit your site and read your listings. It seems more beneficial to not have a token at all for reading data but have one if you plan to write or view more sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

Your point makes sense.

The [OAuth2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) (section 1.3.2) explains this :

> Implicit grants improve the responsiveness and efficiency of some
> clients (such as a client implemented as an in-browser application),
> since it reduces the number of round trips required to obtain an
> access token.

But the industry best practice has changed. [The OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics) document recommends against using the Implicit flow entirely:

> [...]clients **SHOULD NOT** use the implicit    grant (response type
> "token") or any other response type issuing    access tokens in the
> authorization response, such as "token id_token"    and "code token
> id_token", unless the issued access tokens are    sender-constrained
> and access token injection in the authorization    response is
> prevented.

Comment: So in the scenario that companies stop using the implicit flow, how are public APIs (such as Moltin) being protected then if they allow anyone to freely call their APIs?